# Not able to change npm proxy settings

Tags: npm

I was trying to install ExpressJs from npm was using the command:

```
npm i express
```

But I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "express"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 10.7.0.1:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/akhil/npm-debug.log
```

I suspect it is a proxy error. I use previously working under proxy (mentioned in the error 10.7.0.1:8080) but now I didn't want the proxy and was trying to remove it, for the I have tried the commands:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

I have also tried adding -g to the above commands
Also I have used,

```
set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```

When I use the command

```
npm config ls -l
```

It shows both proxy and https-proxy equal to null. But it seems the proxy has not actually changed looking at the error.

Any help on how to deal with this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *set your proxy false*

```
npm config set proxy false
```

After that *clean your cache*

```
npm cache clean
```

If that didn't help you and you are using proxy then try this:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
```

Comment: Thank You so much! Worked like magic! But how did setting proxy false worked but setting null didn't work?